# How to modify a specific column in each dataframe in a list using lapply instead of a for loop

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list of dataframes and am currently using the following for loop:

```
  for (i in 1:length(genotypeGOI)){
    genotypeGOI[[i]]$SEQSTRAND <- '*'
  }
```

But I'd really like to learn how to use lapply properly.

I've tried many different options using the mutate function but nothing is giving me what I want.  My latest attempt is:

```
genotypeGOI <- lapply(X = genotypeGOI, FUN = function(x){
  x <- x$SEQSTRAND, '*')
})
```

But this is giving me an error:

```
Error: unexpected ',' in:
"genotypeGOI <- lapply(X = genotypeGOI, FUN = function(x){
  x <- x$SEQSTRAND,"
```

Basically I would like to know how to change the values in a specific column for each dataframe in a list using lapply and don't really care about this specific problem.

I've looked at the other posted questions related to this and the most similar one says to make a function and to call that in lapply but I really don't want to do that for a one-liner.

Thanks

Comment: What error does it give you? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Or I guess the problem is you're not assigning anything to a column in your `mutate`. Instead of `x <- x %>% mutate_at(vars(SEQSTRAND), '*')`, do `x %>% mutate(SEQSTRAND='*')`

Comment: I'm not looking for this specific example.  I'm just trying to see how to convert the for loop into lapply.  I can't figure out how to modify a specific column in each dataframe in a list with lapply.  I don't seem to be able to use x$ syntax.

Comment: Your example doesn't use `x$` at all so it's not clear what the problem would be. Using `x$SEQSTRAND <- '*'; x` would probably also work (again, hard to tell without a reproducible example). You just need to make sure to have `x` at the end so the function returns the entire data.frame.

Comment: When I use:
genotypeGOI <- lapply(X = genotypeGOI, FUN = function(x){
  x <- x$SEQSTRAND, '*')
})

I get the error:
Error: unexpected ',' in:
"genotypeGOI <- lapply(X = genotypeGOI, FUN = function(x){
  x <- x$SEQSTRAND,"

I've added this to the question as well

Comment: That's not what I suggested. I suggested `genotypeGOI <- lapply(X = genotypeGOI, FUN = function(x){ x$SEQSTRAND <- '*'; x })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command `lapply(genotypeGOI, FUN = function(x) x <- x$SEQSTRAND,'*')` doesn't quite make sense in R coding. Even still, if you just did `lapply(genotypeGOI, FUN = function(x) x[,"SEQSTRAND"] <- '*')` is closer but will still not return what you want:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:10,
                 X = letters[1:10],
                 SEQSTRAND = NA)

lapply(genotypeGOI, FUN = function(x) x[,"SEQSTRAND"] <- '*')

genotypeGOI <- list(df, df, df)

#[[1]]
#[1] "*"

#[[2]]
#[1] "*"

#[[3]]
#[1] "*"
```

To return the data frame with `SEQSTRAND` as a `*`, you can use `lapply` like this (returning the `x` value)

```
lapply(genotypeGOI, function(x) {
  x[,"SEQSTRAND"] <- "*"
  x
})

# [[1]]
#      ID X SEQSTRAND
#   1   1 a         *
#   2   2 b         *
#   3   3 c         *
#   4   4 d         *
#   5   5 e         *
#   6   6 f         *
#   7   7 g         *
#   8   8 h         *
#   9   9 i         *
#   10 10 j         *
#   
#   [[2]]
#      ID X SEQSTRAND
#   1   1 a         *
#   2   2 b         *
#   3   3 c         *
#   4   4 d         *
#   5   5 e         *
#   6   6 f         *
#   7   7 g         *
#   8   8 h         *
#   9   9 i         *
#   10 10 j         *
#   
#   [[3]]
#      ID X SEQSTRAND
#   1   1 a         *
#   2   2 b         *
#   3   3 c         *
#   4   4 d         *
#   5   5 e         *
#   6   6 f         *
#   7   7 g         *
#   8   8 h         *
#   9   9 i         *
#   10 10 j         *
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to stick with `mutate` as had appeared in the original question, this answer'll work:

```
dd<-data.frame(Value=c(1,5,7,9))
ee<-data.frame(Value=c(2,4,6,8))

ff<-list(dd,ee)

gg<-lapply(ff, FUN=function(x){
  x%>%
    mutate(SEQSTRAND ="*")
})
```

We start by making a list of dataframes with `ff<-list(dd,ee)`.  When using the pipe (`%>%`) in the lapply, since we've specified our `x` to be the list named "ff", we write our function to be applied as a reference to `x`.